# ifluatex and ifxetex not in repository

Tags: luatex, installing

trying to run a docker install of tinytex and running into an issue where it can't find ifluatex and ifxetex in the repository. I've tried a few different mirrors to no avail [RIT, dal, etc].

Suggestions on where to look?

```
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running updmap-sys ...
done running updmap-sys.
regenerating fmtutil.cnf in /tmp/texlive/texmf-dist
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luahbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --no-error-if-no-format --byengine xetex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luahbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --no-error-if-no-format --byengine xetex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luahbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --no-error-if-no-format --byengine luatex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luahbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --no-error-if-no-format --byengine luatex.
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luahbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --no-error-if-no-format --byengine pdftex ...
done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luahbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --no-error-if-no-format --byengine pdftex.
tlmgr: package log updated: /tmp/texlive/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr install: package ifluatex not present in repository.
tlmgr install: package ifxetex not present in repository.
tlmgr: package repository http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr install: package already present: dvipdfmx
tlmgr install: package already present: lm
tlmgr install: package already present: luaotfload
tlmgr install: package already present: texlive-scripts
[1/74, ??:??/??:??] install: amscls [32k
```

Comment: ifluatex and ifluatex are distributed as part of the iftex tlmgr package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the help - just following up to say that I switched to a Debian install of TexLive rather than the R installer of tinytex - this sorted the issue out for me :)

Comment: For the record, these two packages have just been removed from TinyTeX, thanks to the PR https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/pull/191.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Yihui :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For R users stumbling on this question:

I switched my dockerfile from

```
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('pander','tinytex'),repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')" \
&& R -e "tinytex::install_tinytex(extra_packages=c('iftex','pdftexcmds','grffile','epstopdf-pkg','lm-math','unicode-math','lualatex-math','filehook'))"
```

to

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
                                        pandoc \
                                        texlive \
                                        texlive-latex-base \
                                        texlive-latex-recommended \
                                        texlive-plain-generic
```

and rmarkdown/knitr/pander etc all work correctly in my docker image now :)

Comment: can you explain this? pandoc and rmarkdown just stopped working for me for the same reason

Comment: Hm, are you also using a docker installation of R/ Rmarkdown/pandoc?

Comment: @invictus not sure if you saw Yihui's comment but the latest pull request on tinytex seems to have fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

Packages `ifluatex` and `ifxelatex` are now a part of `iftex`. It seems you can't download `ifxelatex` by `tlmgr` now.

Check following links:

- https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifxetex,
- https://www.ctan.org/pkg/iftex

For a quick fix, you can remove dependency of `ifluatex` and `ifxelatex`, and require `iftex`. And also replace in the source code `\ifxelatex` and `\ifluatex` with `\ifXeTeX` and `\ifLuaTeX`.

Comment: there is no need to change uses of \ifxetex and \ifluatex, the updated  iftex package defines those commands